# Conditional HTML class depending on page

Tags: php, class, if-statement, directory

I'm looking for a way to get this into PHP:

If the user is on "contact.php", then insert "..."

Right now, I have this:

```
<?php
if(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/contact.php'))
{echo '<li class="current">';}
else{echo '<li>';} ?>
```

However, for some reason this doesn't seem to work.

Also, I was wondering if there is a way to have it apply to multiple pages (in a directory) without using 'array', so basically saying:

If the user is on a file in directory A, then echo "...". If not, then echo "...".

EDIT: 
I figured out why it is not working, but I do not understand. Basically, I edited an HTML5 template, and replaced the common script of every page with a header.php and footer.php. However, the class="current" was in a different place on every seperate HTML page, which is now 1 common PHP header. The function in my header.php works when I link to the header like this:

```
<?php
require "header.php";
?>
```

But it does not work when I link to my header like this:

```
<?php
require "http://localhost/header.php";
?>
```

However, all the other information in my header.php is coming through.. I believe it's just this one function that stops working. 
Am I missing something really simple here? Please forgive me if that is the case...

Comment: What you want is to include another source file into your current file. The first version is correct because it accesses the required file through the local file system. The second option is an actual HTTP-request such as your browser would perform, but in this case it is run on the local network system of your server. That means the PHP code in header.php is executed as if it was an orginal request from the browser, so REQUEST_URI contains /header.php and only the processed content is included into your current file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might not work because stripos will return 0 if the string "/contact.php" is found at the beginning, which is then interpreted as false. You should check the result of stripos with the !== operator against false.

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/contact.php') !== false) { ... }
```

Regarding your other question:
Just split the REQUEST_URI string into its parts and check if the penultimate element matches your directory. Although there might be a better approach in general to your problem.

EDIT:
Based on Can Celik's comment I would suggest you use the parse_url()  function [1] to decompose the entire request URI. Then you can access any part of the URL from the returned array and split the "path" part as I suggested before:

```
$parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$segments = explode("/", $parts["path"]);
$parent_dir = ""
if(count($segments) > 1) {
    $parent_dir = $segments[count($segments)-2]
}
if($parent_dir == "my_parent_dir") {
    echo '<li class="current">';
} else {
    echo '<li>';
}
```

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: What if he is on a page with url parameters like this www.test.com/login.php?redirectuURL=/contact.php ?

Comment: That is certainly true. The best approach is to decompose the entire path, e.g. with the parse_url() function.

Answer (score 1):

stripos() should be hard-compared with FALSE to determine whether it really found the item or not.

Like arrays, the first character in a string is 0 (zero), not 1. If the position of the needle string is at the beginning of the haystack string, then stripos() will return 0 since 0 is the first position of the haystack. But if() will treat 0 as the same as false.

So you should be saying

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/contact.php') !== false)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: What if he is on a page with url parameters like this www.test.com/login.php?redirectuURL=/contact.php ?

Comment: I don't think it's a page with url parameters, but I'm not sure. The URL doesn't look like this at least.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not the problem he's having, and I wanted to answer the specific question, not try to predict the other scenarios he may or may not need.

Edit: And incidentally, that design for a post-login redirect would worry me greatly, and would seem to present some real potential security issues, not to mention the potential to horribly break user flow.

Comment: @KeithTyler: +1 for answering the specific question; and I also agree that this will eventually lead to a broken URI if you add parameters, although I wouldn'd consider it to be a potential security issue to give the desired redirect URL after login as a parameter. Would you clearify your concerns?

Comment: @agent_harris: Not knowing the rest of the application's security considerations, I would fear that an attacker could find unauthorized pages -- or even just create issues by breaking flow -- by "url hacking" the redirect argument. Better would be to use some identifier that isn't directly used as a path, and use some lookup table to map those identifiers onto desired destinations.

Let's say I have a basic access login and I login to url "login.php?redirect=admin.php", then when I login it takes me to admin.php which I should not see because I'm not an admin!

Comment: @KeithTyler: That sounds like a lot of extra work; as long as the parameter is just used for HTTP redirecting (which should anyway be the case considering a restful approach), any resource (also admin.php) is IMHO supposed to check for itself if the current session is allowed to perform an action. Increasing security by hiding something that could anyway be accessed through the adress bar is only "security through obscurity". But sure, you might also put the target URL into the session variable or somewhere else. In the end it is more about personal style and user convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'contact.php'){
    echo '<li class="current">';
} else{
    echo '<li>';
}
```

If your contact page will have any parameters than you can strip out the parameters.

```
$urlParts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
$page = $urlParts[0]; // <-- This will give you just contact.php for your example.
```